# laravel application having same method in controllers

Tags: laravel, controller

I have Laravel application and inside controllers, I have the same method with the same structure in multiple controllers ( most of them but not all of them )

how can I refactor these controllers for cleaner code structure?

can I use a base controller and extend all my controllers or is it possible to use trait for that

## Update :

I use Datatable for most of my controllers and because of that I have `destroyMultiple` and `updateStatus`method in those controllers . and the code content in all controllers are so similar (e.g: only change is in model name ) and I feel bad to copy this method in every 15 controllers I have  ( and as system grows other controllers )

this is my controller code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Library\AdminLib;
use App\Library\Datatable;
use App\Project;
use App\ProjectImage;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Session;

class ProjectController extends Controller {
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index () {
        return view("admin.projects.index");
    }
    
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create () {
        $token = AdminLib::setUploadSession();
        
        return view("admin.projects.create" , compact('token'));
    }
    
    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store ( Request $request ) {
        $this->validate($request , [
            'title' => 'required' ,
            'alt'   => 'required|unique:projects' ,
        ]);
        
        $project         = new Project($request->only([
                                                          'image' ,
                                                          //its image file
                                                          'alt' ,
                                                          'title' ,
                                                          'description' ,
                                                          'meta_keywords' ,
                                                          'meta_description' ,
                                                      ]));
        $project->active = AdminLib::fixSwitch('active');
        $project->save();
        //save images that uploaded ajax ( relate them to this project )
        $token = AdminLib::getUploadSession();
        $images = ProjectImage::with([])
                              ->where('token' , $token)->get();
        $project->projectImages()
                ->saveMany($images);
        #

        $project->projectVideos()
                ->createMany(AdminLib::filterUrl($request->get('videos')));
        return redirect(route('admin.projects.index'))->with('success' , 'Information has been added');
    }
    
    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Project $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit ( Project $project ) {
        $token = AdminLib::setUploadSession();
        return view("admin.projects.edit" , compact('project' , 'token'));
    }
    
    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \App\Project             $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update ( Request $request , Project $project ) {
        $this->validate($request , [
            'title' => 'required' ,
            'alt'   => 'required' ,
        ]);
        $project->fill($request->only([
                                    'image' ,
                                    //its image file
                                    'alt' ,
                                    'title' ,
                                    'alt' ,
                                    'description' ,
                                    'meta_keywords' ,
                                    'meta_description' ,
                                ]));
        $project->active = AdminLib::fixSwitch('active');
        $project->save();
    
        //save images that uploaded ajax ( relate them to this project )
        $token = AdminLib::getUploadSession();
        $images = ProjectImage::with([])
                              ->where('token' , $token)->get();
        $project->projectImages()
                ->saveMany($images);
        //save video
        $project->projectVideos()
                ->delete();
        $project->projectVideos()
                ->createMany(AdminLib::filterUrl($request->get('videos')));
        
        return redirect(route('admin.projects.index'))->with('success' , 'Information has been updated');
    }
    
    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param \App\Project $project
     * @return array
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function destroy ( Project $project ) {
        $ok = $project->delete();
        
        return compact('ok');
    }
    
    public function destroyMultiple () {
        
        $count = Project::with([])
                        ->whereIn('id' , \request('id_list'))
                        ->delete();
        $ok    = true;
        
        return compact('count' , 'ok');
    }
    
    public function updateStatus () {
        //some code to update status
    }
    
    public function datatable ( Request $request ) {
        $datatable = new Datatable();
        $response  = $datatable->setRequest($request)
                               ->setQuery(Project::with([]))
                               ->generalSearch(function ( Builder $query , $search ) {
                                   return $query->where('title' , 'like' , "%$search%")
                                                ->orWhere('id'  , "%$search%");
                               })
                               ->manipulateData(function ( Project $record ) {
                                   $record->action  = [
                                       //todo fix route
                                       'edit'    => route('admin.projects.edit' , $record->id) ,
                                       'destroy' => route('admin.projects.destroy' , $record->id) ,
                                   ];
                                   //todo use model to decorate this
                                   $record->created = "{$record->created_at->toFormattedDateString()} - {$record->created_at->toTimeString()}";
            
                                   return $record;
                               })
                               ->getResponse();
        
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: inheritance is prefered in terms of standard OOP rules. Traits are usefull too but don't abuse :)

Comment: Depends on what refactoring you want to do. There is no one right solution, everything depends on use case. This question is ambiguous without the use case or code

Comment: I updated the question with code @Paras

Answer (score 1):

if you follow REST then your controllers should look the same, and inheritance in this case is not really useful, because generating restful controller with `-r` flag will always give you all the methods you need.

Comment: -r flag will create all the methods but without implementation !! beside I have 2 methods more than resource methods laravel creates. I update the question and add code. maybe it helps clarify my question

Answer (score 0):

All database logic should be the responsibility of the model. If you have multiple destroy and update calls, it's best you extend all your models from the base model and use [Eloquent query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#query-scopes) to implement both methods in your base model.

From Taylor Otwell, creator of Laravel:

> If there's one thing I've learned from PHP is that controllers should
>   do nothing. Those things exist in this ethereal plane, just like this
>   hazy fog that does nothing and passes off stuff to some domain
>   abstraction service layer

Although he also mentions in the same talk that a lot depends on use case and the above is the ideal scenario.